# wxMaxima: how to define the inverse of a function?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I know that we can find the inverse of a function using `solve` *e.g.*

```
f(x):= a*x+b$
[invf]:solve(f=f(x),x);
```

However, I haven't been able to work out how to use this in the definition of a new function. I tried a few things, like:

```
invF(f):=rhs(invf);
```

but the `f` in `rhs(invf)` isn't recognized as the argument of the function `invF(f)`. Is there any way to define an inverse, or would one simply work with this expression and use something like `subst` to evaluate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right-hand side of `:=` isn't evaluated (or even simplified), so anything like `rhs(invf)` in the function body doesn't actually compute the result until the function is called. What's needed here is to ensure that the result is pasted into the function body at the time the function is constructed.

There are at least two ways to do that. The more general way is to define the function with `define` instead of `:=`. Then the body is evaluated when the function is defined. E.g. `define(invF(x), rhs(inv));`.

Another way which only works at the top level (i.e., not inside any function) is to make use of the so-called quote-quote operator, `''`, which has the effect of interpolating the current value of something into the input, as if it were typed in. E.g. `invF(x) := ''(rhs(inv));`.

Quote-quote acts *at the time the expression is parsed* so that can be surprising if it appears in a function. E.g. `y: 123; f(x) := block([y: 2*x], ''y);` then `f(4)` returns 123, not 8. That said, I have found quote-quote to be convenient and helpful -- just have to confine it to top-level stuff.

Comment: This clarifies why my use of `subst` worked, as well.  Thank you very much, Robert!

Answer (score 1):

The following modification of my earlier attempt seems to work:

```
f(x):=a*x+b;
[inv]:solve(f=f(x),x);
invF(x):=subst(x,f,rhs(inv));
```

Not sure why the use of `subst` changes the way the function definition is handled, but it does seem to work. Hope it might be helpful to others!